# Picking up field value using Python regex

Tags: python, regex

This is an example of two lines in a file that I am trying to pick up information from.

```
...
{ "SubtitleSettings_REPOSITORY", FieldType_STRING, (int32_t)REPOSITORY},
{ "PREFERRED_SUBTITLE_LANGUAGE", FieldType_STRING,SUBTITLE_LANGUAGE},
...
```

What I want to do is to find out the 3rd field of this weird data structure for the given string to match to 1st field, i.e.

```
SubtitleSettings_REPOSITORY => REPOSITORY
PREFERRED_SUBTITLE_LANGUAGE => SUBTITLE_LANGUAGE
```

The regx in my Python code can only handles the second line, but not cope with the first line. How I can improve it?

```
import re
...
#field is given a value in previous code, can be "SubtitleSettings_REPOSITORY", or "PREFERRED_SUBTITLE_LANGUAGE"
match = re.search(field+'"[, \t]+(\w+)[, \t]+(\w+)', src_file.read(), re.M|re.I)
return_value = match.group(2)
```

Comment: `(` and `)` are not members of the `\w` character class, so to obtain a match in the two cases, you need to describe the part enclosed between parens and make it optional in the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert `(?:\(\w+\))?`, which allows (and ignores) an optional word in parentheses there:

```
match = re.search(field+'"[, \t]+(\w+)[, \t]+(?:\(\w+\))?(\w+)', line, re.M|re.I)
```

With this, the line matches and you get `'REPOSITORY'` as desired.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
with open("input.txt") as f:
  pattern = "\{ \"(.+)\",.+,(.+)\}"
  for line in f:
    first, third = re.findall(pattern, line.strip())[0]
    print first.strip(), "=>", third.strip()
```

prints

```
SubtitleSettings_REPOSITORY => (int32_t)REPOSITORY
PREFERRED_SUBTITLE_LANGUAGE => SUBTITLE_LANGUAGE
```

where `input.txt` contains

```
{ "SubtitleSettings_REPOSITORY", FieldType_STRING, (int32_t)REPOSITORY},
{ "PREFERRED_SUBTITLE_LANGUAGE", FieldType_STRING,SUBTITLE_LANGUAGE}
```

**Breakdown:**

- `\{ \"(.+)\"` matches strings with the structure **{ + space + " + text + "** and extracts **text**
- `,.+,(.+)\}` matches strings with the structure **, + text1 + , + text2 + }** and extracts **text2**